# $_FILES is always empty

Tags: php, objective-c, pdf, afnetworking-2, uploading

I am uploading a PDF to my server through my web-service, but $_FILES always seems to be empty regardless of what I do.

The program that will be uploading the PDF is an OSX program (via AFNetworking). I have ruled this out as a possibility of causing the issue as when I attempt to upload the file through 'CocoaRestClient' (similar to POSTMAN on chrome) I get nothing. In CocoaRestClient I am setting my ContentType to 'multipart/form-data'.

The PDF I am attempting to upload is 478kb so I do not think that size is the issue.

My PHP code is below. At the moment I am just trying to see if anything is in the $_FILES array at all.

```
<?php

header('Content-type: multipart/form-data');

$fileName = $_FILES['PDF']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['PDF']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['PDF']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['PDF']['type'];

$response = array("filename" => $fileName,
                  "tmpName" => $tmpName,
                  "fileSize" => $fileSize,
                  "filetype" => $fileType,
                  "FILES" => $_FILES);

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

This is the response I get from the JSON

```
{"filename":null,
 "tmpName":null,
 "fileSize":null,
 "filetype":null,
 "FILES":[]}
```

This is my objective-C code.

```
                [manager POST:pdfURL
                   parameters:nil
    constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:pdf name:@"PDF" fileName:filename mimeType:@"multipart/form-data"];
    }

                      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, id responseObject) {
                        [self checkForErrorInResponse:responseObject];

                        [delegate pdfUploadedSuccessfullyWithResponse:responseObject];
                    }

                      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, NSError *error) {
                          [delegate pdfFailedToUploadWithError:error];
                      }];
```

After using POSTMAN to determine that my php is working correctly, I can conclude that my objective-C code is causing the bug. What is strange however, is that even though my php code returns null's, Charles is telling me that the PDF IS being uploaded!

Comment: There is no HTML code, it is being done through an OSX program. However I am debugging through CocoaRestClient.

Comment: Can you please post the applicable objective-c code and a `var_dump` of `$_FILES`.

Comment: post any code as we have to see what it is sending actually

Comment: the program might not be uploading it as `$_FILES["PDF"]` but as `$_FILES["userfile"]` or something else all together, try `print_r($_FILES)` and see if its really empty or not

Comment: Hey Rudiger Kidd, tried that.
Unfortunately just got an empty array.

Comment: If it's an empty array then nothing is being received. Are there definitely no errors or exceptions being thrown? You could try seeing exactly what's being sent using an app like: [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html)

Comment: Hey Joe, just tested out using a similar program - Charles. Nothing seems to be sent. Will investigate further.

Comment: Using POSTMAN I can conclude that my objective-C code is causing the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!
The problem was that I wasn't setting the request serializers HTTP header field to 'application/pdf'.

```
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/pdf" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Answer (score -1):

This might help you if you forgot adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in the form element. Try below code.

```
<form action="demo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> ... </form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Ejaz. I am not using a HTML form to send the data, so unfortunately this does not help.
Thanks anyways though!